# Hibernate: "could not read column value from result set ... could not deserialize"

Tags: hibernate, serialization

I have a Java class that I want to persist to the database:

```
public class ClassA implements Serializable {
    //
    // other fields not shown
    //

    private ObjectType objectType;  // an enum that indicates the actual class stored in the "object" field
    private Object object;
}
```

Here is the Hibernate mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
    <class name="x.y.z.ClassA" table="ClassA">
        <!--
           other properties removed
        -->

        <property name="objectType" column="OBJECTTYPE">
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">
                    x.y.z.ClassA$ObjectType
                </param>
                <param name="type">12</param>
            </type>
        </property>

        <property name="object" column="OBJECT" type="serializable"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I use Hibernate to insert an instance of ClassA into the database, a row is inserted, and I see that the "object" field is defined as a longblob.  However, when I use MySQL Workbench to look at the "object" field's data, it tells me that the data length is 255 bytes.  The object that I am trying to store in the "object" field contains some strings whose combined lengths add up to more than 255 characters.  Is it being compressed before being stored into the longblob column?

The problem I am having is when I try to use Hibernate to query for the row that I inserted.  Hibernate returns 0 rows, and in the hibernate log I see the following error:

```
8167 [Thread-32] INFO  org.hibernate.type.SerializableType - could not read column value from result set: OBJECT195_0_; could not deserialize
```

If the object isn't being compressed when Hibernate stores it in the longblob column, then I guess that's what is causing the "could not deserialize" error.  I know it is larger than 255 bytes but MySQL Workbench says it is 255 bytes long so the object must be getting truncated for some reason.

But if the object is being compressed, then maybe Hibernate can't deserialize it because it's just a java.lang.Object type and it doesn't know what the actual object type is.  If this is the case, then is there a way to write a custom deserializer for Hibernate?  Because the actual object type is indicated by the "objectType" field, so a custom deserializer could check the "objectType" field and then know how to deserialize the "object" field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Hibernate by default sets the maximum size of the longblob column to 255 bytes.  I changed the line in the mapping file to:

```
<property name="object" column="OBJECT" type="serializable" length="2147483647"/>
```

That solved the problem.